# How i can play a sound from firebase to android studio with kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I been searching all over Internet about How i can play a sound from firebase to android studio with kotlin but i just found with java

Comment: well, convert the java code to kotlin or rework it ? if you have code and you're stuck with something specific, add it here

Comment: Have you tried a_local_nobody's suggestion? Show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: public void play_song (view v) {
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new_MediaPlayer();
    try { mediaPlayer.setDataSource("");
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()){
            @override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer){
                mp.start();
            } };
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

Comment: @Badr_G9mer if you are going to provide code, provide it in the question, not a comment. Just [Edit] the question and tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what went wrong. No one is going to write this code other than you.